# HTML Media Capture ludei cocoonJS support

Tags: android, html, cocoonjs

I'm using Ludei CocoonJS to build my html5 Application.

I use HTML5 Media Capture (http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/) to acquire an image that I want to decode to have a qr code.

I'm using this tag to launch the camera default camera or upload a photo from device:

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='picChange(event)'/>
```

It works on the web browser both on safari for Mac and on android firefox.

The problem is when I build my apk application using Ludei, when I tap it nothing happens. Same problem using CocoonJS Launcher on my android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just asked that in the cocoonjs forums

http://support.ludei.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200901435-Q-getUserMedia-support-for-WebCam-

Looks like Chrome blocks getUserMedia from resources loaded via file:// but that behaviour can be overridden by launching with --allow-file-access-from-files

Hopefully this is something the cocoonjs guys can achieve.

//Adam

Comment: So at the moment we can't do nothing to make it working... I'll try to use cordova API to access Camera. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have some success using this http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/200807797-Canvas-Webview (note, not WebView+) which allows "[you] to render a transparent webview on top of the Canvas+ OpenGL ES rendering context and it also provides a bidirectional communication channel between them."

Its precisely what I need, hope it fits your needs also!

//Adam